# Librosa: conflicts between numba and numpy on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, numba

I am facing the following issue: I wrote some code to analyse audio with librosa and a library called "Timbral_Audio" in python on my windows PC (Python 3.8.7).

The following libraries are installed on the PC:

```
pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ ------------
appdirs            1.4.4
audioread          2.1.9
certifi            2021.10.8
cffi               1.15.0
charset-normalizer 2.0.12
decorator          5.1.1
future             0.18.2
idna               3.3
joblib             1.1.0
librosa            0.9.1
llvmlite           0.38.0
numba              0.55.1
numpy              1.18.0
packaging          21.3
pandas             1.4.2
pip                20.2.3
pooch              1.6.0
pycparser          2.21
pyloudnorm         0.1.0
pyparsing          3.0.9
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2022.1
requests           2.27.1
resampy            0.2.2
scikit-learn       1.1.0
scipy              1.8.0
setuptools         49.2.1
six                1.16.0
sklearn            0.0
SoundFile          0.10.3.post1
threadpoolctl      3.1.0
timbral-models     0.4.0
urllib3            1.26.9
```

So, I copy the code over to my Raspberry Pi 4 (Python 3.9.2). When I try to install librosa an llvm error occurs. This can be fixed by installing clang and then installing llvm (version 11).
Then I can install librosa (0.9.1) successfully. (It also installs the following dependencies: `Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 audioread-2.1.9 certifi-2022.5.18.1 cffi-1.15.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 decorator-5.1.1 idna-3.3 joblib-1.1.0 librosa-0.9.1 llvmlite-0.38.1 numba-0.55.1 numpy-1.21.6 packaging-21.3 pooch-1.6.0 pycparser-2.21 pyparsing-3.0.9 requests-2.27.1 resampy-0.2.2 scikit-learn-1.1.1 scipy-1.8.1 setuptools-62.3.2 six-1.16.0 soundfile-0.10.3.post1 threadpoolctl-3.1.0 urllib3-1.26.9`)

However, when try to run the code

```
import librosa
```

with thonny, the error

```
    RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/timbraltestroot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .convert import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/convert.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import notation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/notation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from ._filters import *  # noqa: F401 F403
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import _nd_image
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

comes up. This means that a newer version of numpy has to be installed. So I tried to install a newer version of numpy (1.22.1) but then the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/timbraltestroot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .convert import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/convert.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import notation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/core/notation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numba
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _ensure_critical_deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 140, in _ensure_critical_deps
    raise ImportError("Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less")
ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less
```

occurs. So the new problem is that numpy 1.22.1 is not compatible with numba 0.55.1.

I read that this issue occurs because numba is not yet compatible with numpy 1.22.1.
But why does the code work on the windows computer which uses numpy=1.18.0 and numba=0.55.1 (there is no version 0xf / 0xd error)? Is this due to the different python version? Or is the library somehow compiled differently?
Is it possible to compile the library on the raspberry pi against version 0xe or something like that?
Is there any other solution? Or do I have to wait until numba supports numpy 1.22.1?

Many thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,
BlackOut

Edit: Just tested with python 3.9.2 on windows. Works aswell.

Comment: Hello BlackOut, how do you solve the issue? Because I encounter the same issue.

Comment: Hi Susan, I think the order of installation was important. First numpy 1.21.6 then librosa. If there already is a version of numpy installed, the librosa installer will not install an own version of numpy which is incompatible.